# switch to a new activity, instead of switching fragments, when jfeinstein10's slidingmenu list item is clicked

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I have seen a few questions raised on this topic (for e.g.: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/5)  but I am still unclear. I hope somebody can clarify this.

Context:

See https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

I have an android app that organizes screens by activities and fragments (i.e.) each screen is an activity containing one or more fragments.
The new requirement is to add a sliding menu (similar to what this library provides).

Issue:

It appears from the examples and discussion that the right model would be to have just 1 MAIN ACTIVITY that will then switch in/out fragments belonging to the different screens. In fact the author mentions in the above thread: "If you were to launch Activities based upon the list selection, then you would not have the behavior where you swap the views that you're talking about. " and also "You can't put an Activity into the above view. That doesn't really make sense when you think about what an Activity is. ".

Why doesn't it make sense? Obviously, I am missing the point here.

Question:

Given that my project already contains multiple activities (one corresponding to each screen), is my only option then to re-organize the project to have JUST 1 MAIN ACTIVITY, in order to use this library? Or alternatively, is there any way to launch a new activity when a list item in the sliding menu is clicked, and still observe the sliding menu behavior, [**EDIT**- added the last part to be more clear] or in other words, on how exactly to use this library within my existing app design.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can't have an `Activity` inside another and activities are completely different from views as stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.

Now, to answer your question, it all depends on how you want your app to behave. You could have your activities with the sliding menu implement the `onClosedListener` and switch to the selected activity from there. This will give you the animation of closing the menu before switching activities. It will also give you a weird effect since every time you select something from your menu you'll see the animation of a new activity coming to the front.

I think the best approach would be to have a "common purpose" between all your sliding menu options. For example, in one of my projects I have to allow the users to select between lists of different types of data. When the user selects anything from the menu, I load a new list fragment into the right corner where he may choose the item he wants to view or edit. That's the app entry point and also the only place were I have a sliding menu in my app. It is pretty much the same for every app that implements this UI design pattern. Look at google+, currents and youtube where the side menu lets you choose which feed or content to show. Once a user makes a selection, just open a new activity for the selected item (a g+ post, a video, a news article, a tweet or whatever it is).

Your app doesn't have to have lists of different data or anything like that to use the sliding menu, but keep in mind that the activity with the sliding menu should have a clear, focused goal with respect to its functionality and purpose. Having a sliding menu because many other apps have one is a bad choice, you should use it with a specific objective. Also keep in mind that applying the sliding menu everywhere would interfere with the platform's [navigation pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) and lead to an overall bad user experience since it wouldn't behave as the other apps.

Comment: I am following a navig. pattern very similar to the youtube app - action bar, whose 'up navigation' opens the sliding menu. You have mentioned above - ".. just open a new activity for the selected item". The slidingmenu library shows examples of switching 'fragments' (not activities) on sliding menu item selection. When I tried switching 'activities', I did see the weird effect of a new activity coming to front, as you have mentioned. Unfortunately my question (edited) above still remains open, on how exactly to use this library within my existing app design.

Comment: I assume you have a `MainActivity` of some sort, the entry point of your app that serves as a router for the other activities. Just have that activity turn into your sliding menu activity. Load a fragment to browse each different type of content based on the selected menu item. You'll only need the browsing fragment in the `MainActivity`, which will always be replaced. Open another activity to handle individual items. Since you already have a working app, reusing existing activities for viewing each type of content is a better option than changing it all to work with a single activity.

Comment: maybe a little late but i found a solution. I had create a class with my sliding menu and other activities extends this class (so all contains the sliding menu without insert it in all the layout files). For the weird effect of the new activity you can just remove the animation using : intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to place an Activity into the above view because the Activity is the main controller for the view of each screen. The Activity also shows views and keeps track of Fragments (which in turn are mini controllers, with or without their own views). So placing an Activity in the above view would mean that you would place an Activity in an Activity... Wich is impossible.

From what I can derive from your text I think it would be wise to read through the Android developer guide on Activities and Fragment again (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) to get a better understanding of how the concept of Android works.

Now to your question:

I am not clear on what you are trying to achieve but if you want your app, with menu to behave like, say, the Google+ app then one way of doing it is to implement a base class that extends the Activity class (or what ever base Activity used in your project) and let the base set the SlidingMenu. Then you would simple extend your base Activity in each of the Activities that are supposed to have a menu.

You could also do it the way you describe it, but then you would end up with a classic example of a God object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). It's a neat way to practice your Fragment juggling skills and switching between Fragments instead of starting new Activities does have it's use cases, but I still wouldn't recommend it for a project with more then a few views.

Comment: I had already tried the approach you suggest above (1 base activity with others deriving from this). I will try out the approach suggested by @ebarrenchea to switch fragments based on menu item click. Thanx for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that came closest to the issue I had - http://www.verious.com/article/polishing-the-sliding-app-menu/. Scroll down to the bottom of the page to see the last section titled "Using the fly-in app menu between Activities". This is one option if you have a lot of activities in your existing app and want to avoid extensive re-factoring. I haven't tried this out yet but its worth being aware of.